# What is the figure which is throughput with processor means in oracle java official document

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The “Java Platform, Standard Edition HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide”, explains [its figure 1-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/gctuning/introduction-garbage-collection-tuning.htm#GUID-A48F272E-A6C1-45A0-9A8B-6D5790EB454C__PERCENTAGE_TIME_GC) like below

> *The red line is an application spending only 1% of the time in garbage collection on a uniprocessor system. This translates to more than a 20% loss in throughput on systems with 32 processors.*

[image: Garbage collection cause problems in scability system]

I don't understand what this figures really mean.
Does it mean that, in the condition which is fixed gc time, the GC affects throughput of CPUs because of its suspension?

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation section in question?

Comment: *Is it means that, in the condition which is fixed gc time, the GC affects throughput of CPUs because of its suspension?* Yes. And as the number of processors increases, a 1% GC time equates to 30% of clock time across 32 cpus. While 30% GC leads to almost 100% of the time spent in GC. Basically, this is a re-statement of Amdahl's law.

Comment: Basically I'm asking because there isn't enough information in your question to determine the answer.  I *think* the quote refers to the old stop-the-world mark-and-sweep GC, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @markspace Thanks for your help. I saw it at  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/gctuning/introduction-garbage-collection-tuning.htm#JSGCT-GUID-223394DF-2E27-4F5D-A7DF-83151EB577BB

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Thanks for your comment. but I still don't understand that is it means the throughput is better when the processor is fewer? I thought like that because when we see only redline, it indicates the thoughput is better when the processor less than five rather than when the processor number is 32.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation text in the document where you found this graph is:

> The graph in Figure 1-1 models an ideal system that's perfectly scalable with the exception of garbage collection. The red line is an application spending only 1% of the time in garbage collection on a uniprocessor system. This translates to more than a 20% loss in throughput on systems with 32 processors. The magenta line shows that for an application at 10% of the time in garbage collection (not considered an outrageous amount of time in garbage collection in uniprocessor applications), more than 75% of throughput is lost when scaling up to 32 processors.

The link below the graph says:

> The graph models an ideal system that's perfectly scalable with the exception of garbage collection (GC). It plots the number of processors (x-axis) against throughput (y-axis). It contains six plotted lines labeled 1% GC, 2% GC, 3% GC, 10% GC, 20% GC, and 30% GC. Each line represents the changing throughput for an application that spends the specified percentage of time used for garbage collection on a uniprocessor system versus on a multiprocessor system. The graph is described in the text that precedes it.

---

So ...

1. This is a model, not a graph of real measured performance.
2. The model is idealized.  It assumes that the application is perfectly scalable (apart from GC).
3. It is illustrating what happens when you *don't* make the garbage collection scalable; e.g. if there is only one GC thread and it doesn't operate in parallel with application threads.
4. The 1% GC, 2% GC, etc lines represent different modeled GC loads on a uniprocessor system.  So the 1% line represents the case of an application running on a uniprocessor system where the application threads generate a GC load that could be collected using 1% of the available CPU.
5. The throughput represents the *useful* (application) work that is being done by a busy application; i.e. the time (GC overhead) that is *not taken up with garbage collection or waiting for the GC to finish.
6. The throughput is measured as a percentage of the available CPU time on a system with the given number of processors.

So, for example, at the 30% GC level, the throughput for a 32 core system will be roughly 1/10th of the theoretical throughput of the hardware.  It  will waste roughly 9/10ths of the available CPU time waiting for garbage collection to complete!

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), it states that "the overall performance improvement gained by optimizing a single part of a system is limited by the fraction of time that the improved part is actually used".

You can calculate the graph.